# Na+ / K+ ATPase: How does it restore resting membrane potential?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, action-potential, neuron

Could not find any sources talking about this (in a clear manner). If the Na+ / K+ ATPase pumps 3 Na+ out for every 2 K+ it pumps in, thus making the cell more negative, why is the Na+ / K+ ATPase used to restore resting membrane potential following hyperpolarization? Wouldn't that must make the cell more negative, which is the opposite of what we want?

Comment: The Na+ / K+ ATPase is *not* "used to restore resting membrane potential following hyperpolarization", it is used to maintain the concentration gradient of sodium and potassium.

Comment: @BryanKrause: How are the concentrations of Na+ and K+ outside / inside the cell rebalanced after hyperpolarization then?

Comment: Try also https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76166/ambiguity-about-the-relation-between-membrane-potential-and-concentration-gradie/76167#76167 https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57064/why-is-it-possible-to-calculate-the-equilibrium-potential-of-an-ion-using-the-ne/57066#57066 https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66166/are-cells-electrically-neutral-or-charged-to-setup-the-membrane-potential-across/66174#66174 in addition to the marked duplicate https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/77919/why-does-resting-potential-not-become-continually-more-negative

Comment: The sodium-potassium pump does keep the concentrations of Na+ and K+ constant in the long term, but that's not necessary for transient changes like you get from receptor activation or action potentials, those are governed by opening and closing of passive ion channels.